# Javascript variables in getElementbyID

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain to me why the following code returns null? The code in '"' + id + '"' returns the correct value. but not when used in conjunction with getElementById.

```js
function ReadMore(id) {
  if (document.getElementById('"' + id + '"').style.display === 'none') {
    document.getElementById('"' + id + '"').style.display = 'block'
  } else {
    location.replace(id);
  }
}
```

```html
<article>
  <a href="/article-four.html"><title>Lincoln and Kennedy Coincidences</title></a>
  <p>
    Not long after the assassination of President John F. Kennedy in 1963, the a list of seemingly amazing coincidences between the two men’s lives appeared, and it has been widely and continuously reprinted and circulated ever since:
  </p>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ReadMore('article-four')">Read More</a>
  <p class="read-more" id="article-four">
    Abraham Lincoln was elected to Congress in 1846. John F. Kennedy was elected to Congress in 1946. Abraham Lincoln was elected President in 1860. John F. Kennedy was elected President in 1960.
  </p>
</article>
```

Comment: Your IDs don't have double quotes. The quotes in the markup are just delimiters to define the ID within them. It should just be `document.getElementById(id)`

Comment: That's because `'"' + id + '"'` expression produces a `"article-four"` value. Literally, with quotes around. You don't have an object with such an id.

Comment: Amazed by how many beginners think they need the quotes around it.

Comment: @epascarello serialisation/encoding is a hard problem for non-beginners as well

Comment: Please format your code appropriately

Comment: If you markup is consistent so that the element being fetched is always directly after the one being clicked, then you could pass it directly by doing `ReadMore(this.nextElementSibling)`. Then you don't need to select by ID at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired id is article-four (no quotes), not "article-four" (with quotes).

document.getElementById("article-four") passes just the string article-four as the argument.  When you explicitly add the quotes *to the parameter* they get passed along too.

Change your code to just document.getElementById( id )